# Mean Value Inequality for $C^1$ function defined on $\partial \Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded, open, connected subset of $R^2$, with $\partial \Omega$ of class $C^1$.

Suppose also that we have a $C^1$ parametrization $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of $\partial \Omega$ by arc-length, with $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)=x$.

Assume that $g: \partial \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^1$.

I was wondering if there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
|g(z)-g(x)| \leq C |z-x| \quad \forall z \in \partial \Omega,
$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

This would be a trivial consequence of the mean value theorem if $g$ was defined on a convex open set.

In our case, instead, suppose that $t_z \in (a,b)$ is such that $\gamma(t_z)=z$.
Let $\gamma_{x,z}$ be the shortest path in $\partial \Omega$ connecting $x$ and $z$.
Without loss of generality, suppose that $t_z < \frac{1}{2}(b-a)$, so that $\gamma_{x,z}=\gamma|_{[a,t_z]}$.
Since $g \in C^1(\partial\Omega)$, we have $h:=g\circ\gamma \in C^1([a,b])$ and there is $M>0$ such that $|h'(t)| \leq M $ for every $t\in [a,b]$.
Integrating, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
g(z)-g(x) &=\int_a^{t_z} \frac{d}{dt}(g(\gamma(t))dt \\
&=\int_a^{t_z} h'(t) dt
\end{align}
$$
and
$$\begin{align}
|g(z)-g(x)|&\leq M(t_z-a) \\
&=M L(\gamma_{x,z}), 
\end{align}
$$
where $L(\gamma_{x,z})$ is the length of $\gamma_{x,z}$.

Now the natural thing to do seems to write

$$
|g(z)-g(x)| \leq M \frac{L(\gamma_{x,z})}{|z-x|}|z-x|.
$$

So we obtain the desired result if we know that
$$
\sup_{z\neq x, z \in \partial\Omega} \frac{L(\gamma_{x,z})}{|z-x|} < \infty.
$$

So the question is: is this true?

We know that $L(\gamma_{x,z}) \leq \frac{1}{2} L(\gamma) < \infty$, so the only issue is when $|z-x|$ is very small, namely when $z$ is very close to $x$.

In this case, I think that the ratio should be approximately equal to $1$. Is this correct?

We have
$$
\gamma'(a) = \lim_{t_z\to a} \frac{z-x}{t_z-a}
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{t_z\to a} \frac{|z-x|}{L(\gamma_{x,z})}=|\gamma'(a)|=1.
$$

Do you think that the result and the reasoning is correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you just parametrize the boundary and pull back to the closed interval; then the "usual" Mean Value Theorem applies. All you need is that the speed of the parametrization is bounded (and you're positing an arclength parametrization).

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin and thanks for your comment. If I understood correctly what you mean by pull back, then $h = g \circ \gamma$ is the pull back of $g$ to the closed interval, and the MVT gives us $g(z)-g(x)=h(t_z)-h(a)=h'(c)(t_z-a)$ and hence $|g(z)-g(x)| \leq M (t_z-a)$. I would like to replace $t_z-a$ on the RHS with the euclidean norm $|z-x|$, possibly by changing the constant $M$ to some other $C$.

Comment: Ah, I would have expected intrinsic distance in $\partial\Omega$. To relate extrinsic distance to intrinsic, curvature bounds on $\partial\Omega$ will probably solve your issue.